# WordPress multi site network setup on local server shows sub-directories error

Tags: multisite

We are trying to setup a multisite network on local server. But in network setup, where we were expecting to radio selects for either sub-domian or sub-directories there we can see

**"Because your install is in a directory, the sites in your WordPress network must use sub-directories."**

The set is taken from existing wordpress site on local. For SEO purpose we want to select sub-directories for multisite. Please provide solution in detail as i am the only one who works on wordpress in my team.
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the message says you have no choice: since your local installation is a directory your subsites will be subdirectories and cannot be subdomains.. That fit your needs, so just go on..
https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Installing_a_Network

Comment: I completed the installation but now after i created a new site its not visible in sites under network Admin. And if i go through the Sites>All Sites>newsite dashboard i see broken page saying **This page isn’t working ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

Comment: read carefully the documentation on the link in my answer, there are several configuration steps you've to follow. Sometimes setup a network is not so linear, there might be .htaccess conflicts as well as other issues